# Как домен управляет веб-приложением при обработки запросов браузера

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Пытаюсь понять жизненный цикл веб-приложения, построенного на **ASP.NET MVC 5**. На хостинге стоит веб-сервер **IIS 8.5**.

Погуглив, сразу наткнулся на официальную [статью](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) по этому поводу. Думаю, многие со мной согласятся, что по крайней мере с первого раза понять даже основные **укрупненные слои** тяжело, не говоря уже запомнить их.

Но мне все и не надо на первое время. Для меня сейчас важно понять в **укрупненном виде**, правильно ли я понимаю начальный маршрут запроса, отправленного от браузера. И в какой момент мое веб-приложение запускается и когда закрывается.

Нашел одну иллюстрацию по этому поводу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду отталкивается от нее. Правда тут говорится о **IIS версии 5**. Не знаю насколько это актуально.

Итак, поехали:

1. Опубликовал приложение на хостинге. *Имя домена (www.mysite.ru)*.
2. Пользователь 1 вводит в браузере `www.mysite.ru`.
3. Запрос натыкается на IIS.
4. IIS создает домен. *Для работы с одним сайтом есть только один домен.
   Домен не перегружается и не пересоздается при каждом запросе*.
5. В этом домене для обработки запроса `mysite.ru` запускается наше
   веб-приложение (HttpApplication 1). Происходит обработка запроса и
   Пользователю 1 возвращается ответ. После того как ответ отдали
   приложение HttpApplication 1 заканчивает свою работу.
6. Пользователь 1 теперь пускает запрос `mysite.ru/home/report` и для
   обработки данного запроса домен **вновь** запускает приложение
   HttpApplication.

**Вопрос:** Для обработки каждого запроса каждый раз наше приложение запускается все заново? Это типа: для обработки каждого запроса, домен **каждый раз** запускает наше приложение, помещает туда запрос и после получения ответа закрывает приложение *(alt+f4)*.

Comment: С чего вы вообще взяли, что приложение может стартовать заново? При чем тут вообще alt+f4?

Comment: @PavelMayorov 1) на иллюстрации я вижу три отдельных `HttpApplication`. Это ведь и есть **отдельно** запущенные наше приложение? 2) Но сейчас еще раз более внятно прочитал обсуждение [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/13.php) и там говорится: `для обслуживания каждого запроса создается свой объект контроллера и все, что вы запускаете в нем также работает для текущего запроса`. Вообще запутался.

Comment: Нет, HttpApplication - это не приложение, а его представление в контексте запроса.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не хочется конечно быть слишком придирчивым к иллюстрации, но _количество меток_ и _раскраски_ этих меток соответствуют значками _Клиент_ и я подумал, что обработку запроса клиента ведет свой личный `HttpContext/Контроллер`. Но как теперь выясняется запросы **даже от одного клиента** обрабатываются в **разных контролерах**, так?

Comment: Разумеется. Весь контекст запроса создается заново на каждый запрос.

Comment: [Жизненный цикл HttpApplication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiujcPFFinA)